# I need to find a company or trusted cryptocurrency professional to review my smartcontract

Tags: ico

I have been searching to find someone to review a smartcontract for my companies up and coming ICO.  I have only found companies that hope to do this in the future but no real business that reviews the code.  After some research it seems an individual that is very known in the crypto space is the way to go.  Any help on this would be great!

Comment: (http://www.solidified.io/)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a smart contract audit. There are several companies that provide this service ([Zeppelin is one of the industry leaders](https://zeppelin.solutions/security-audits)) but it's most likely going to cost you over 10k USD. Remember though, that's basically the gold standard; your other option is to find ethereum developers and experts through online communities that are willing to help for a more reasonable price.

I will warn you against cutting too many corners, security and integrity is absolutely crucial for smart contracts.